# is there a way to embed youtube/twitch in to a div?

Tags: html, youtube, twitch

i want to have one page for my twitch and youtube pages  what i did was:

```
 <style type="text/css">
            html, body { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
            div { width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left; }
            #div1 { background: #DDD; }
            #div2 { background: #AAA; }
            #div3 { background: #777; }
            #div4 { background: #444; }

            </style>
  <div id="div1">
      <object type="text/html" data="https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <object type="text/html" data="https://www.twitch.tv/xwarpewpew/" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</div>
```

i try to do it with iframe didnt work seem to be blockt or same sort of problem with the https 
 
is there a way to do this ?

Comment: What are you trying to display? A video or some other kind of content?

Comment: id like to display the dashboard of my livestream ,the page it self as the live stream to so i guess u can say this a video too

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a div, you could just use an Iframe. With this you can display websites & videos.

Here is a page with everything you need to know: <del>http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp</del>

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe
https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe

You can also do this only for videos, like this code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_I64Xz9m168" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: like i sayd i allrdy try iframe and it didnt work but i gave it one more shot from the site u gave me " <iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard"></iframe>"  page as nothing in it   ,i dont need only the video i need the page it self still think the https is the problem it seem to work fine with any other page i tryd